# Can an Interface class be Implemented by Multiple Classes?

Tags: java, class, interface, extends

> Can an Interface class be implemented by multiple classes?

This is my question and honestly I do not even know what it is asking. I believe that it may be something like this:

```
interface Bicycle {

    private void getBikeName();

    class MountainBikes {

    }

}
```

Although maybe the question is a typo and it means to say;

> Can an Interface class be extended by multiple classes?

In which case I think the answer is true. However, I'm still not sure what the above question is asking. Could anybody shed some light?

Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean to _implement an interface_?

Comment: What's an "interface class"? In any case, an interface can obviously be implemented by multiple classes--if that weren't the case it would defeat the purpose entirely.

Comment: Implementing an interface would mean to design a Java class containing an interface type class with header functions. I have no idea what an "interface class" is because my professor does not know what she is talking about.

Comment: @bob No it wouldn't. It would mean simply writing `class A implements Interface` and implementing the necessary methods inside it. 'Interface class' is certainly sloppy terminology, but it isn't sufficient to prove that your professor doesn't know what she's talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an `interface` can be implemented by multiple classes. You could have figured this out by testing it:

```
class FirstClass implements MyInterface {

}

class SecondClass implements MyInterface {

}

interface MyInterface {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes an interface can be implemented by multiple classes.

This would go in Shape.java, it is an interface:

```
public interface Shape {
  public int getArea();
}
```

This would go in Square.java it is a class that implements the Shape interface:

```
public class Square implements Shape {
  private int sideLength;
  public Square( int sideLength ) {
    this.sideLength = sideLength;
  }
  public int getArea() { return sideLength *2; }
}
```

This code would go in Circle.java it is also a class that implements the Shape interface:

```
public class Circle implements Shape {
  private int radius;
  private double PI = 3.14;
  public Circle( int radius ) {
    this.radius = radius;
  }
  public int getArea() { return PI*radius*radius; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of your tricky question. The answer is yes

public class Test extends Bicycle.MountainBikes {
    public void getBikeName() {}

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hi");
    print();
}
```

}

public interface Bicycle {
    public void getBikeName();

```
public class MountainBikes {
    public static void print() {

        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

}